# Object Pronoun or possessive pronoun

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I wonder why option (C) is wrong? I think it is still  possible that the possessive pronoun “hers” is used to replace “her birthday”

Ms. Greelay’s colleagues, who discovered that her birthday is on Thursday, are preparing a special celebration for -----------
(A) her
(B) she
(C) hers
(D) herself

Comment: In examples like yours, genitive "hers" typically serves as complement to "of", not "for", for example "I'll never forget that birthday of hers last year". But in this case, where someone is the recipient of something, the preposition "for" requires the accusative pronoun "her".

Comment: It's got to be the accusative ***her*** because the only credible preceding referent for ***her*** is ***Ms Greelay***, and that makes sense. The possessive ***hers*** has no credible antecedent - to fill that slot would require a preceding reference to either ***multiple*** birthdays, or ***someone else's*** birthday (so ***hers*** could be used to identify ***her birthday*** as distinct from any others). For example, *Ms. Greelay’s colleagues, **who attach great importance to birthdays**, are preparing a special celebration for **hers*** (where ***hers*** refers back to ***birthdays***).

Comment: I'd leave off the 'for anything'. It's implicit.

Answer (score 1):

If the pronoun is supposed to mean "her birthday," then C is the only right answer.  It's the only one that can mean "her birthday."

If the right answer is A, then it doesn't mean "her birthday" but means "Ms. Greelay."

Anyway, you might hear that sentence with "hers" in a context of:

Mr. Johnson's colleagues know it's his birthday on Thursday and aren't doing anything special for his birthday.  *Ms. Greelay’s colleagues, who discovered that her birthday is on Thursday, are preparing a special celebration for **hers**.*

Answer (score 0):

It's her (A) is correct. Why?
"her" is a pronoun. "herself" can be grammatically used, but it isn't supposed to be in the context.